# constructors with different array-arguments java

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, overloading, junit5

I am trying to create different constructors with array arguments. Arrays has different dimensions. But in practice 2-dimension constructor calling anytime.

```
public Network(String [] adjacentMatrixRows) throws AdjacentMatrixCreationExeption {
    this.adjacentMatrix = new int[adjacentMatrixRows.length][];
    String [][] stringMatrix = new String[adjacentMatrixRows.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < adjacentMatrixRows.length; i++) {
        stringMatrix[i] = adjacentMatrixRows[i].trim().split(" ");
        this.adjacentMatrix[i] = new int[stringMatrix[i].length];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < stringMatrix.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < stringMatrix[i].length; j++) {
            try {
                this.adjacentMatrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(stringMatrix[i][j]);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e){
                throw  new AdjacentMatrixCreationExeption("Wrong data format in String[].");
            }
        }
    }
}
public Network(String[][] adjacentMatrix) throws AdjacentMatrixCreationExeption {
    this.adjacentMatrix = new int [adjacentMatrix.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < adjacentMatrix.length; i++){
        this.adjacentMatrix[i] = new int[adjacentMatrix[i].length];
        for (int j = 0; j < adjacentMatrix[i].length; j++) {
            try {
                this.adjacentMatrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(adjacentMatrix[i][j]);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e){
                throw  new AdjacentMatrixCreationExeption("Wrong data format in String[][].");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe the problem is caused, because  array consist of arrays. But how can i resolve it?

UPD:
I am trying to call constructors in the Junit tests:

```
` Throwable exception = assertThrows(AdjacentMatrixCreationExeption.class, ()-> {
             Network network = new Network(new String [][]{{"1", "a"},{"1", "1"}});});
        assertEquals("Wrong data format in String[][].", exception.getMessage());`

     Throwable exception2 = assertThrows(AdjacentMatrixCreationExeption.class, ()-> {
                Network network = new Network(new String []{"1", "a", "1", "1"});});
            assertEquals("Wrong data format in String[].", exception.getMessage());
```

Output of JUnit tests:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <Wrong data format in String[].> but was: <Wrong data format in String[][].>
Expected :Wrong data format in String[].
Actual   :Wrong data format in String[][].
```

Comment: Please show in your question how you try to call the constructors.

Comment: @AndyTurner, Updated.

Comment: I've tested your code but it give me compilation errors. Please fix the errors before than post the complete code of Network class.

Comment: @KDavid-Valerio, what are you talking about? It compile in my computer. If you are talking about JUnit tests, they must be runned with "@"Test anotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! In my JUnit tests, i always used single exception called "exception". But in the second test, i had to use "exception2"

```
Throwable exception2 = assertThrows(AdjacentMatrixCreationExeption.class, ()-> {
        Network network = new Network(new String []{"1", "a", "1", "1"});});
    assertEquals("Wrong data format in String[].", exception2.getMessage());
```

Thanks to everybody. Problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

I did the test below

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = new String[1];
        String[][] array2D = new String[1][1];

        Network n1 = new Network(array);
        Network n2 = new Network(array2D);
    }

}
```

This is Network class with both constructors:

```
class Network {
    public Network (String [] adjacentMatrixRows){
        System.out.println("Array");
    }

    public Network (String [][] adjacentMatrixRows){
        System.out.println("2D Array");
    }
}
```

I got the following output:

> Array
>
> 2D Array

Comment: You are asking for clarification here, so you should really post this as a comment (you can link to e.g. an ideone example to demonstrate the behaviour you describe, rather than trying to post in a comment).

Comment: I removed my question, so now my post is an answer.